# How to run Specflow feature/scenarios in cmd using vstest.console.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface, command-prompt, specflow

I have a feature file defined like

```
Feature: Portal Sign in
    In order to login to my portal
    As a User
    I have input user id and password

Scenario: User Login
    Given I have entered username and password 
    When The user clicks on Login button
    Then logged in successfully pop up message should be displayed
```

I tried this cmd:

```
vstest.console.exe tests.dll /TestCaseFilter:"FullyQualifiedName~PortalSigninFeature"
```

but it returns with no test matches for the given test case filter. Am I missing anything?

Also how do you suggest to run scenarios using cmd?

**Edit:**

In case of scenario Outline like the one below

```
Scenario Outline: Multiple User Login
    Given I have entered <username> and <password>
    When The user clicks on Login button
    Then logged in successfully pop up message should be displayed

Examples:
|username|password|
|User1   |pwd1    |
|User2   |pwd2    |
```

When I run the below cmd

```
SpecRun.exe run D:\SpecFlow\bin\Debug\MySpecFlowTests.dll --filter testpath:"Scenario:Multiple+User+Login"
```

Discovered tests appear as 0.

Should I change anything to make it work for scenario outline?

Comment: Always try a query with no filtering to make sure there is data and the items you are searching for are in the database.

Comment: Do you actually have a feature and scenario like this? The example feature is a copy and paste from [my answer in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64284114/3092298).

Comment: Well @Greg Burghardt, sorry about that.
Went for the lazy way and pasted the same snippet.
One of my scenario is as above.
To give you more info, I have created several feature files in my project and want to be able to run from cmd based on the feature file. I can provide a tag to each scenario/scenario outline under a feature file and achieve filtering but I wanted to know if there was specifically a way to filter based on feature file/scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran this in jenkins from a command line I had the below. I am using SpecRun for a runner. This did require a RunSettings file.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow" vstest.console.exe /settings:E\MyPath\To\RunSettings\ E:\MyPathTo\Test.dll /ResultsDirectory:E:\MyPath\ /TestCaseFilter: "(TestCategory=MyTag)"
```

I created a folder called Jenkins and the RunSettings and .srprofile both resided in that folder.

RunSettings file pointed to the .srprofile

```
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations for SpecFlow+ Runner -->
  <SpecRun>
   <Profile>Jenkins/MyTest.srprofile</Profile>
   <GenerateSpecRunTrait>false</GenerateSpecRunTrait>
  <GenerateFeatureTrait>false</GenerateFeatureTrait>
  </SpecRun>
</RunSettings>
```

If you are using SpecRun as a runner, you can also run this from a cmd line. Update the runner version accordingly.

```
cd E:\Path\to\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.3.*\tools\net461
SpecRun.exe run PathTo/My.srprofile --baseFolder E:\Path\To\bin\Debug --filter "@TagL" --log specrun.log
```

To run by a Feature Name, you would use:

```
SpecRun.exe run D:\Path\Jenkins\My.srprofile --baseFolder D:\Path\bin\Debug --filter testpath:"Feature:MyFeature*" --log specrun.log
```

wild card will match anything starting with "MyFeature".

https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Filter.html

Comment: Thanks @Dazed for the insight, but my question is how to filter execution based on a feature or scenario? By using /TestCaseFilter: "(TestCategory=MyTag)", we can filter based on the tag provided for the scenario/scenario outline. Here TestCategory has to be assigned to a tag name but are there any properties available to support filtering by feature/scenario? If so could you explain the usage?

Comment: Updated my answer showing syntax for running by a feature name. Make sure you are matching the Feature based on FileName.feature.  So if your file is named MyFeature.feature and inside the file you have Feature: My Feature, your filter will be "MyFeature".

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: SpecRun.exe provides testpath filter type to filter by feature. Any idea if the same can be achieved with vstest.console.exe? Any property by which that is possible @Dazed?

Comment: Or any idea how I can use SpecRun.exe to read a list of feature files/scenarios from txt file and run them all in one go?

Comment: Sorry @Dazed to be bombarding you with so many queries, another query I have is how to filter when I have scenario outline? testpath:"Scenario:Multiple+User+Login" doesn't seem to work, updated my question for more details

Comment: How are you executing your tests? Are you using Jenkins or any kind of automation or are you just manually executing? Truthfully I would be using tagging. I add a Tag for my feature name to all tests for that feature. In doing this, I can execute by tag name in VS or from Jenkins or command line for the entire feature.

Comment: Both manually and Jenkins. 
The manual execution covers a variety of flavors and here I want to be able to achieve execution in different ways depending on either scenario, feature or tags.
Manual execution would involve running bat files